# Python, add items from txt file into a list

Tags: python, file-io

Say I have an empty list `myNames = []`

How can I open a file with names on each line and read in each name into the list?

like:

```
>     names.txt
>     dave
>     jeff
>     ted
>     myNames = [dave,jeff,ted]
```

Answer (score 55):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = f.readlines()
```

The others already provided answers how to get rid of the newline character.

**Update**:

[Fred Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10077/fred-larson) provides a nice solution in his comment:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Comment: change `open(file, 'r')` to `open('names.txt', 'r')`. `file` is a build-in type which shouldn't be used as variable name either... Otherwise, good solution.

Comment: If we wanted to incorporate the `strip` into this solution, I'd probably do it like so: `myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]`.

Comment: @Fred: Good idea, if you want to write it as answer, I will remove it from mine.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks.  Let's just call it a collaborative effort.  8v)

Comment: Using the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines), you can do all this in one line: `myNames = file('names.txt').read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 13):

```
f = open('file.txt','r')

for line in f:
    myNames.append(line.strip()) # We don't want newlines in our list, do we?
```

Answer (score 9):

```
names=[line.strip() for line in open('names.txt')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#function call
read_names(names.txt)
#function def
def read_names(filename): 
with open(filename, 'r') as fileopen:
    name_list = [line.strip() for line in fileopen]
    print (name_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good case for map and lambda

```
with open ('names.txt','r') as f :
   Names = map (lambda x : x.strip(),f_in.readlines())
```

I stand corrected (or at least improved). List comprehensions is even more elegant

```
with open ('names.txt','r') as f :
    Names = [name.rstrip() for name in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way to read a file and put every lines in a list:

```
from __future__ import with_statement #for python 2.5
Names = []
with open('C:/path/txtfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    Names.append(lines.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Names = []
for line in open('names.txt','r').readlines():
    Names.append(line.strip())
```

strip() cut spaces in before and after string...