# comparing the unicode character from user input to unicode characters in file

Tags: python, unicode

So i have this code so that i can input the unicode string from the user

```
print "Enter a nepali string" 
split_string=raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))
```

And i have in file some unicode string and if that unicode string matches as substring in the user input string then i have to split that string . suppose i have "सुर" in file and if that matches "सुरक्षा" which is input by user then i want only "क्षा" in output

```
with codecs.open("prefixnepali.txt","rw","utf-8") as prefix:
    for line in prefix:
          line=ud.normalize('NFC',line)
          if line in split_string:
             prefixy=split_string[len(line):len(split_string)]
             print prefixy
          else:
            print line
```

But when i run the program i get

दि

सुर

रु

Which are the unicode string in files when i input "सुरक्षा" in the terminal.
Can i know what is wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be simple: a line read from file has newline character at its end.  Use `splitlines` as advised in [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines) and [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines)

```
with codecs.open("prefixnepali.txt","rw","utf-8") as prefix:
    for line in prefix.read().splitlines():
          line=ud.normalize('NFC',line)
          if line in split_string:
             prefixy=split_string[len(line):len(split_string)]
             print prefixy
          else:
             print line
```

And btw, `line in split_string` will look for occurrence of `line` anywhere within `split_string`.  If you're looking for exactly the prefix match, you should use `split_string.find(line) == 0` or `split_string[0:len(line)] == line`.