# Syntax Error with <>

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to do this assignment:

This is what I have and I am getting a syntax error on >

Pasted code:

```
# Specify where the input and output file is

InputFile = open('C:\Python\unsorted_fruits.txt', 'r')
OutputFile = open('C:\Python\sorted_fruits.txt', 'w')

# Read the input file

Fruits = InputFile.readlines()

# Sort the items in the list
Fruits.sort()

# Remove the blank lines and write the file
for fruit in Fruits:
    if fruit <>"\n":    # if fruit is blank, skip the write
        OutputFile.write(fruit) # otherwise write the fruit to the output file


# Close the input and output file
InputFile.close()
OutputFile.close()
```

Comment: `if fruit <>"\n":` What the _heck_ are you doing?

Comment: Oh, is that what that is? What language uses that?

Comment: Isn't `<>` like some deprecated syntax for `!=`

Comment: Worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15233739/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace "<>" with "!=", since "<>" is deprecate in python3,which can be used as "!=".

Comment: Was `<>` _ever_ used in Python? o_O I didn't ever see it anywhere outside BASIC.