# Response 404, but URL is reachable from python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a webcrawler, but currently the **404** error occurs when calling `requests.get(url)` from the requests module. But the URL is reachable.

```
base_url = "https://www.blogger.com/profile/"
site = base_url + blogs_to_visit.pop().rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
r = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# Printing some values for debugging
>>> print site
https://www.blogger.com/profile/01785989747304686024

>>> print r
<Response [404]>
```

However, if I hardcore the string `site` for the requests module as the exact same string. The response is **202**.

```
site = "https://www.blogger.com/profile/01785989747304686024"

# Printing some values for debugging
>>> print site
https://www.blogger.com/profile/01785989747304686024
>>> print r
<Response [202]>
```

What just striked me is that it looks like a hidden newline after printing `site` the first time, might that be what's causing the problem?

The URL's to visit is earlier stored in a file with;

```
for link in soup.select("h2 a[href]"):
    blogs.write(link.get("href") + "\n")
```

and fetched with

```
with open("foo") as p:
    return p.readlines()
```

The question is then, what would be a better way of writing them to the file? If I dont seperate them with "\n" for eg, all the URL's are glued together as one.

Comment: you could "strip" the values before you save them. pop().rsplit(..)[-1].strip() or use p.read().splitlines as suggested in @Marc L. Allen's  answer.

Comment: You can read lines with: `lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('filename')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines), perhaps use:

```
with open("foo") as p:
    return p.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
r = requests.get(site.strip('\n'))
```

instead of:

```
r = requests.get(site)
```