# Reading values of two lines and write in one line with python

Tags: python, file

I have a file with this format:

```
611    2856     618    2582   94075   94107   94065   94068
101071   94104
598    2856     618     611   93995   94107   93992   93991
94075   94065
612    2834    2821    2812   94087  101577   94085   94081
101558  101557
```

I need to read the lines and to rewrite them so:

```
611    2856     618    2582   94075   94107   94065   94068 101071   94104
598    2856     618     611   93995   94107   93992   93991 94075   94065
612    2834    2821    2812   94087  101577   94085   94081 101558  101557
```

I have tried something like this:

```
f2 = open('new_file.txt', 'w')
    f1 = open('old_file.txt')
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):    
        print(repr(line))               
        f2.write(line)
        i = i+1
    f1.close()
f2.close()
```

But it is not working as it writes again every line. I need to read two lines and write them in one.
Any suggesitons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to read the lines into a list, or mess about with line numbers, you can just iterate directly over the file lines:

```
with open('oldfile.txt') as fin, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line[:-1] + ' ' + next(fin))
```

**contents of newfile.txt**

```
611    2856     618    2582   94075   94107   94065   94068 101071   94104
598    2856     618     611   93995   94107   93992   93991 94075   94065
612    2834    2821    2812   94087  101577   94085   94081 101558  101557
```

---

```
line[:-1] + ' '
```

removes the newline char at the end of the long lines, and replaces it with a single space; I'm pretty sure that this is faster than doing `line.replace('\n', ' ')`, but I haven't timed it.

As with Graipher's solution, if the file *doesn't* have an even number of lines, then the last line will not be copied, but I assume that's not an issue for your data.

Answer (score 1):

The lines returned by [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) still contain the [newline `'\n'` at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines). You must [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) them:

```
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f2:
    with open('old_file.txt') as f1:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        # lines = f1.read().splitlines()  will even save you the stripping
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):  # line: 'foo bar \n'         
            f2.write(line.strip())
            if i % 2:  # linebreak only every other line
                f2.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a buffer variable to store every second line like so:

```
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fout:
    with open('old_file.txt') as fin:
        buffer = ""
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                buffer = line.replace('\n', '')
            else:
                fout.write(sep.join((buffer, line)))
                buffer = ""
```

With `sep = " "` or whatever else you use for separation.

This assumes you have an even number of lines, otherwise the last line will not be written.