# File's string dont match

Tags: python, file, if-statement

here's the problem: i have a file ,,file.txt''.It is compossed by 11 words.
Good.
Now i have the code :

```
with open('/root/file.txt', 'r') as f:
 data = f.readlines()
 print data[10]
```

It outputs :

```
Password
```

But when i enter :

```
if data[10] == 'Password':
 print 'yes'
else:
 print 'no'
```

It outputs:

```
no
```

Can i know why ?I alredy tried to do ,,str(data[10])" but i get the same output : no. How i can do to get the yes answere ?

Comment: try `data[10].strip()=="Password"`. readlines includes line terminator.

Comment: Each line ends with a newline character `'Password\n'`.

Comment: see /questions/15513433/python-readline-string-literal-never-returns-true

Comment: Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines

Comment: repr(data[10]) will illustrate your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `readlines()` you get a list with each line as a member of the list, this include the `\n` (return line code).

Print the whole list to see what I am saying.

```
with open('/root/file.txt', 'r') as f:
 data = f.readlines()
print data
```

To avoid the `\n` use this code:

```
data[10].strip() == 'Password'
```

If you just need to print something if the word `Password` is in there, try this code:

```
if 'Password' in data[10]:
  print 'yes'
```

Comment: Thanks, it workedd.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because in file "password" is stored as "password\n"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcIJ7.png

Comment: Thanks for answere.