# Other methods of reading a file without newlines

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python and was wondering if it's possible to write the below code differently, but have the same function. The purpose of this code is to split `\n` and remove spaces from the right:

```
contents = readlines()
stripped_contents = [(element.rstrip()) for element in contents]
```

Comment: The code is fine (but you can get rid of the parentheses surrounding `element.rstrip()`), why would you need another method of writing? Other ways would not be as good as yours’

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `readlines` if you're going to iterate over the file(?). Also, use better names like "line" instead of "element".

```
stripped_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
```

If you're going to use stripped_lines immediately as an iterable and only once, use a generator expression instead.

```
stripped_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in file)
```

Comment: I'll need to use stripped_lines more than once, but would it still work?

Comment: Also, do I get rid of the double ( brackets?

Comment: @User426190: You mean the start of this: `[(element.rstrip()...`? Yes. `element.rstrip()` is a single expression and doesn't require extra parentheses.