# requests.get returns 400 bad url when given a variable containing a url, but not when given a string with the same url

Tags: python-3.x, file, url, python-requests

I have a program that reads some URLs from a text file, gets the page source with requests.get, and then uses beautifulsoup4 to find some information.

```
f = open('inputfile.txt')
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
for line in f:
    x = 0
    z = len(line)
    r = session.get(line[x:z])
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

This returns an HTTP 400 Bad Request - Invalid URL. However, when I do the same thing except type out the URL as a string, everything works (although I only get one URL).

```
f = open('inputfile.txt')
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
for line in f:
    r = session.get('http://www.ExactSameUrlAsEarlier.com')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

How would I fix/modify this to allow me to cycle through the multiple URLs I have in the file? Just for clarification, this is what the inputfile.txt looks like:

```
http://www.url1.com/something1
http://www.url2.com/something2
```

etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if there is only one url in the `'inputfile.txt'` does it still give you a 400? Also have you logged out `line[x:z]`, just to make sure it is a valid url getting pulled out?

Comment: Yes, I have logged the output of `line[x:z]`, it returns a valid url. When I copy paste the url that `line[x:z]` contains directly into the `requests.get()` statement, it works. I have not tried with only one url in the input file, I'll try and see how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop over the lines in the file, not the filehandle. Your for loop should be:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    url = line.strip()
```

There are other ways of stripping whitespace from the line, have a look at this post: [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15233340/4047084)

Comment: Great, this worked. My issue appeared to be that there was a stray `\n` at the end of the url. Thanks!