# Why is a newline being added at the end of my strings?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a small question. I noticed that, for some reason, when I use the `+` symbol when joining two variables, Python automatically uses a newline.

```
for i in range(o):
    a = Before.readline()
    b = After.readline()
    if a == b:
        lines.append(" \n")
    else:
        plus = a + b
        lines.append(a + b)

Final.writelines(lines)
```

This would result in a list with values as such (Notice the `'B\nC\n'`)

```
[' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n',
 ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n',
 'B\nC\n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n', ' \n']
```

Assuming that I have initialized the files `Before`, `After`, and `Final` correctly, what should I do to remove these newlines and just add a space? I would prefer to do this without using many libraries.

EDIT : I do know about the `.strip()` method. It is indeed very helpful, to remove the new lines. However, I seem to have phrased my question a little wrong. I was *also* wondering about how to add the new lines, as `a + ' ' + b` doesn't really seem to work. How would I do this?

DOUBLE EDIT : I'm stupid. I put the wrong variable in the appending area. Nevermind, and thanks anyways!

Comment: Python includes the trailing line end character(s) on a `readline()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines)

Comment: @metatoaster Perhaps, although the OP is reading line by line, and the top answer in your suggested duplicate suggests using `.splitlines`, which reads the whole thing into a list, and the OP may not want to do that. OTOH, other answers, eg Martijn Pieter's show how to trim lines one by one.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, sorry. I appear to have written the wrong thing. You are indeed right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Before.readline()` and `After.readline()` are including the newlines in the file you are reading. To remove the trailing newlines and whitespaces, you can:

`Before.readline().strip()`

Then if you want to add newlines in your `a+b` line, you will need to format it explicitly how you want, in any way you want. For example:

- `a + ' ' + b`
- `"{} {}".format(a,b)`
- `a + b + "\n"`
- etc

You could also only perform `.strip()` on `a` when you are adding it to the list. So many possibilities!

Comment: To remove only newline characters at the end, `rstrip('\n')` should to be used.

Comment: This is the right method to remove the newline, but how would I get the space in the middle? I can't seem to get that with the first bullet. Edit : Nevermind, I forgot a bit. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: How does the first bullet not work? It explicitly adds a space in the middle.