# Cannot authenticate to SSH server with correct credentials (username and password) read from a local file

Tags: python, arrays, ssh, paramiko, readlines

I'm making a small program that connects into an SSH server, testing multiple usernames and passwords that are inside a .txt file. The problem I'm having is when it get to the correct username and password it doesn't connect, or at least my `if` statement doesn't properly say it.

If I do pass it as regular variable or just set the `username = 'correct user' ,password = 'correct password'`, it works. Here's part of the code, I'm testing in a local environment with a Linux VM:

```
# read files
fs = open('users.txt','r')
users = fs.readlines()
fs.close()
fs = open('passwords.txt','r')
psswds = fs.readlines()
fs.close()

# connect and test the password
for user in users:
    for psswd in psswds:
        try:        
            print(usuario)
            print(senha)
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            con = ssh.connect(ip,port,username = user,password = psswd)
            if con is None:
                print ('yes')
                break
            else:
                print ('nop')
            SSHClient.close()
        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
            print('User and/or password incorrect')
```

Comment: What is your output? You have a nested `for`. This means you want to try every username with every password. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, that's what i wanted, the output is always 'User and/or password is incorrect', until it finishes with an error. If I do put, manually, the correct user and password it gets inside the 'YES'

Comment: Have you tried printing the usernames/passwords you get? Maybe there's some whitespace or other stuff that shouldn't be there? Or maybe you're getting rate-limited and after a few failed attempts, it just blocks you from trying again?

Comment: When I print it, it shows the correct user and password, doesn't seem to be a white space in it. it does seem like i'm getting limited, but if I put the correct user and pass in the first position of the file, it still doesn't work. Could it be the breaking of the line in the file?

Comment: Try  printing a formatted text inside quotations, so you can see whether there's a trailing space or something - `print('"{}"'.format(user))` (+ the same for password). Or just try passing `user.strip()` and `psswd.strip()`, so it any whitespace from beginning or end of the string gets cut of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `readlines`, it keeps trailing new line characters in the lines.

So you are actually connecting with wrong credentials as both your username and password contain new line, which is not a part of the correct credentials.

See [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15233340/850848).

Comment: Oh. Interesting! I always iterate over the lines and because of that I've always thought `readlines` returns the same elements in a list. :o

Comment: Thanks Martin, can't test at the moment, but as soon as I'm back home, I'll test it, pretty sure that was the problem though, when h4z3 mentioned it, it clicked.