# Why does the function "len()" return an answer that is 1 character longer than the actual string?

Tags: python

I have created a Python program that removes words from a list if they are not a certain length. I have set up a `for` loop that cycles through my list and checks if each word is a length of 3 or greater. My code is as follows:

```
import string

text_file = open("ten-thousand-english-words.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()

open('SortedWords.txt', 'w').close()
for i in lines:
    print(len(i))
    if len(i) >= 4:
        sortedFile = open("SortedWords.txt", "a")  # append mode
        sortedFile.write(i)
sortedFile.close()
```

I wanted to create a new file that only copies the word over if it is 3 characters or longer.

For some reason it reads all the words in the list as 1 character longer than they actually are (e.g. the word “Hello” would return a length of 6 even though the number of letters is 5).

I fixed this by making it so that the length it looks for is 4 instead of 3, and it worked properly. I couldn't find any information about this issue online, so I decided to post this in case anyone knows why this happens.

Comment: You are not reading words, but instead lines. Being that you are reading a text file, then each line is terminated with a line terminator.

Comment: Trailing whitespace (e.g. a newline)? Try `print([i])` to see.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines

Answer (score 3):

Each line in a file has a "\n" at the end of it which indicates a newline. We can't see this character with a text editor, since the text editor automatically converts it to a new line, but rest assured it's there. When you read a file in python using `readlines()`, this "\n" character is preserved. This is why you are getting a length of 1 more than expected.

Here's some code to understand what's going on:

`somefile.txt`

```
apple
banana
cow
```

`script.py`

```
with open("somefile.txt") as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        print(repr(line))
>>> 'apple\n'
>>> 'banana\n'
>>> 'cow\n'
```

The `repr` function in python will print the literal representation of the string (ie it won't write a newline when it sees "\n", it will just print it as is). If we didn't use `repr` before printing, our output would be:

```
apple

banana

cow
```

Notice there are extra lines in between each string since python is printing the 2 newline characters: 1 from the string itself, and 1 which is added to the end by default from the `print` function.

To get rid of the new line character, we can use `my_string.strip()`, which will removing any trailing or leading whitespace:

```
with open("somefile.txt") as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        print(repr(line.strip()))
>>> 'apple'
>>> 'banana'
>>> 'cow'
```

Answer (score 0):

Every line ends with `'\n'`, and that's the '+1' you see

Comment: Please explain, why.

Answer (score 0):

Your program may be as simple as

```
with open("ten-thousand-english-words.txt", "r") as lines:
    with open("SortedWords.txt", "w") as sortedFile:
        for line in lines:
            if len(line) >= 4:
                sortedFile.write(line)
```

---

*The analysis of your program and the explanation of the mine one:*

1. Other people explained you why the lengths are longer, so instead of `>= 3` you correctly used `>= 4`.
2. Your `import string` is useless.
3. Your command

   ```
   open('SortedWords.txt', 'w').close()
   ```

   is *useless* (simply remove it and make the changes which I describe  below), because it opens the file and immediately closes it, effectively

   - creating an empty file, if it doesn't already exist,
   - empties its content, if it existed.

   Once more, it is *useless*.

   It seems that the only reason for doing it is your later command for repeatedly opening an empty file in the append mode:

   ```
   if len(i) >= 4:
       sortedFile = open("SortedWords.txt", "a")     # append mode
       sortedFile.write(i)
   ```

   But:

   - Opening an already opened file does *nothing.*
   - Why open / close a file repeatedly? You may simply open it in the *write* mode and then write to it in your loop:

     ```
     sortedFile = open("SortedWords.txt", "w")     # NO append mode - WRITE mode
     if len(i) >= 5:
         sortedFile.write(i)
     ```
4. Instead of manually closing an opened file, use the so-called *context manager* (i.e. the `with` statement) for automatically closing it:

   ```
   with open(...) as f:
       ...
       ...

   # after dedent the file is automatically closed
   ```
5. To make the program more bullet-proof, remove eventual whitespaces before / after words (including the `\n`) using the `.strip()` method.

   In this case

   - use the `>= 3` comparison,
   - add the `\n` symbol when writing a word (i.e. the line) to the file:

   ```
   with open("ten-thousand-english-words.txt", "r") as lines:
       with open("SortedWords.txt", "w") as sortedFile:
           for line in lines:
               line = line.strip()
               if len(line) >= 3:
                   sortedFile.write(line + "\n")
   ```