# Joining 2 lines in python out of .txt file (line 148 and line 149)

Tags: python, python-3.x

started a few days ago with python coding, atm doing some work on my discord bot.

my problem atm is that i cannot join 2 lines out of a .txt file in my print output.

the code itself works exactly as it should.

my output atm:

```
Spieler Online:
864
```

expected output:

```
Spieler Online:864
```

the method i'm actually using is

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
lines=fp.readlines()
print (lines[148] +lines[150])
```

tried so much things from google/stackoverflow but nothing gets me the expected output.

thanks a bunch for every idea.

Comment: You have `\n` on the end of every line since `.readlines()` does not strip that off.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lines end with '\n' (newline character), so when printed you also print the '\n' which gets translated into printing two lines.

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
print(lines[148].strip('\n') + lines[150].strip('\n'))
```

Comment: Are you sure ? I thought `.readlines` reads the file and splits the resulting string at `\n`

Comment: Your print statement should not be within the `with` statement

Comment: thanks a bunch, the .strip('\n') just did that what i wanted

Comment: actually readlines returns the lines without stripping the '\n' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines

Comment: @astrochun true, fixed

Comment: @0x9 perfect! now we fixed it witht he suggestion of the fellow user so that it is better! if the issue is solved, please consider marking it as such

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Join() method to merge two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to print 2 different lines, both of the lines have '\n' at the end. In your print statement you are essentially saying print("Spieler Online:\n864\n").
If you want to print both of them on the same line you will have to strip the '\n' from the first line. To do this you can for example use your_string.rstrip("\n")

Comment: thanks for the xplanation, the .strip('\n') did exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In the print statement, you can use the argument 'sep' to your advantage.

Just instead of:

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()
    print (lines[148] +lines[150])
```

Use:

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()
    print (lines[148],lines[150],sep=' ')
```

The sep argument helps to change the separation between the two strings from the default separation, i.e., \n to whitespace (' ').

Answer (score 0):

try

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()
    print (lines[148].split('\n')[1]+' '+lines[150].split('\n')[0])
```