# python: How to display data of a text file

Tags: python, list, file, readline

I am trying to read this text file and display its data. I should report product name, its value & most valuable product. I added at the end what I have tried doing so far:

```
Here is how the text file looks like:
item name 1 ex: hats 
quantity of item 1 ex: 12 
unit price of item 1 ex: 5.9   
item name 2 ex: jacket
quantity of item 2 ex: 13
unit price of item 2 ex: 29.9


Expected output
12 hats at 5.9 the unit. total value: 70.8
13 jackets at 29.9 the unit. total value: 390
total inventory value: 460.8
most valuable inventory: jacket: 390
```

what I've tried doing so far:

```
filename = "store.txt"

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()

content_list = [content[i * 3:(i + 1) * 3] for i in range((len(content) + 3 - 1) // 3)]

total_value = 0

for items in content_list:
    value = float(items[2])*(float(items[1]))
    print(items[1],'', items[0], '@ $', items[2], '. Value: $', value)

    total_value += value


#max_value = max(value)

print('')
print('total value: '+ str(total_value))
#print('Highest value item: ' + str(max_value))
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: yes my bad, I will edit and add what I've tried doing.

Comment: I just added the new edit

Comment: it is considered more `pyhonic` (better practice) to use `with` instead of `open` and `close`, because the with statement automatically closes thus avoiding potential errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting a particular thing sliced from the text file you can use

python    re package

[link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex) if want to understand more about this package

```
      re.split(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

this will return a list

```
       lis = [my_list[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(my_list) + n - 1) // n )] 

       n=size you want to break them in 
       my_list=the list you want to break

      


     file = open("store.txt")

     lis=[]
     for line in file:
     if(line.startswith("item")):
         item_name=line[line.find(":")+1:]
         lis.append(item_name.strip())
     elif(line.startswith("quantity")):
         quantity=line[line.find(":")+1:]
         lis.append(float(quantity))
     elif(line.startswith("unit")):
         unit=line[line.find(":")+1:]
         lis.append(float(unit))

    


     content_list = [lis[i * 3:(i + 1) * 3] for i in range((len(lis) + 3 - 1) // 3)]
     print(content_list)
     total_value=0
     lis2=[]
     for items in content_list:
          value = (items[2])*(items[1])
          print(items[1],'', items[0], '@ $', items[2], '. Value: $', value)
          lis2.append(value)
          total_value+=value


      max_value = max(lis2)

      print('')
      print('total value: '+ str(total_value))
      print('Highest value item: ' + str(max_value))
```

Comment: is it possible to split an array into multiple arrays of 3 elements?
in this sense, im trying to do this: 
`['carrots', '10', '1.2', 'apples', '13', '0.6', 'bananas', '16', '1.7']`

`->[[carrots, 10,1.2], [apples,13,0.6]...]`

Comment: yes it is possible,i just wrote that in my answer how you can do that

Comment: I managed to do it and converted it the array to a tuple:
`(('carrots', '10', '1.2'), ('apples', '13', '0.6'), ('bananas', '16', '1.7'))`
Im not sure how to approach it, should I use indexes ?

Comment: oh okay, I just saw your answer. Maybe a list will be easier to treat than a tuple

Comment: tuple is immutable were as list is mutable so it is easier to work with list and if you want to update the values you can do that in list

Comment: nevermind, i did it, ty a lot. Sadly, can't upvote cos I dont have 15 rep but you have my the upvote of my heart

Comment: can I ask one last question. Please check my new edit. I don't know how to display the highest value. the value is equal to the last calculated value. I was thinking if I could store each value iteration into a list and there find its maximum.. I am confused. Sorry for bothering @justjokingbro

Comment: just checking it out i will tell you

Comment: good i just checked it when i posted the code

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. Here is one (popular method) to get started:

```
filename = "file.py"

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

print(content)
```

You would then need to apply the logic required (to extract and manipulate the text) and write that back to a different file or provide as an output.

Comment: i tried it, however please check output:
`['carrots\n', '10\n', '1.2\n', 'apples\n', '13\n', '0.6\n', 'bananas\n', '16\n', '1.7\n']`

How could I remove the \n (new line) ?

Comment: with this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines    which in summary is `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: thank you, that worked. I guess I will split the array into multiple array of 3 element each and do the treatment from there

Comment: Absolutely,  for this you are probably better using `pandas.read_csv()` depending on how the file is structured.