# PYTHON/PRINT wrong output

Tags: python, list, printing, output, txt

I've made a code where python reads from a file and then proceeds to print a specific line:

```
with open('crypto.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines(1)
crypto = str(lines)
print(crypto)
```

But the output is for example:
`['bitcoin\n']` how do i remove `['\n']` to only get `bitcoin` as an output ?

I know that with `f.read()` there is no brackets and `\n` but I can't choose a **specific** line to read - or can I?

here is the txt file:

```
bitcoin
ethereum
cardano
sandbox
```

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines

Answer (score 0):

Foud the answer!

```
f = open('crypto.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
line = lines[0]
print(line)
```

output ex:  `bitcoin`