# Understanding Python strip() with escape characters

Tags: python

I am accessing a text file of the form

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
...
```

with the following code:

```
names = []
with open('./[path]/text_doc.txt', mode='r') as file:
    names = file.readlines()

for name in names:
    name = name.strip('\n')

print(names)
```

This produces the following list, and I have no idea why:

```
['Name1\n', 'Name2\n', 'Name3\n', ...]
```

I don't understand what in my code is failing to remove these trailing newline characters – `names` is identical before and after the for loop, which doesn't make any sense to me as what is in the for loop should explicitly remove the newline characters from each entry in the list.

Comment: Or more specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines

Comment: Because you never modified your list, `names`. You simply created *new strings* and assigned them to the local variable `name`

Comment: "which doesn't make any sense to me as what is in the for loop should explicitly remove the newline characters from each entry in the list." No, it doesn't modify any of the objects in the list, nor does it modify the list itself.

Comment: Consider, `s = "hello"; s.strip("o"); print(s)`

Comment: Your loop does not modify `names`, it only stores each strip result in `name`, and overwrites it each time. That’s why `names` does not change before and after the loop.

Comment: `names = [name.strip('\n') for name in names]` would work, though, basically by making a new version of names.