# Is there a way to split lines from text when turning into an array in python

Tags: python, jupyter

Is there an alternative way to split lines from a text file without using the `\n` in the code? When I use `\n` to split the text lines, it's a little bit annoying that `\n` also got printed out in the array lines. here is the code that I use so that the text lines can be split when turning into an `array`

```
Combined = open("dictionaries/Combined.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
Example = open("dictionaries/examples.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")

for web in Combined:
    Combined_result = re.search(r"([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*", web)
    Text = (Combined_result.group())
    Example.write((Text+'.web'+'.co.id'+"\n"))

Combined.close()
Example.close()

sample = open("dictionaries/examples.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
websamples = sample.readlines()

websamples
```

And this is the output that I got, the `\n` doesn't look good at all when seeing the array output.

```
['auth.web.co.id\n',
 'access.web.co.id\n',
 'account.web.co.id\n',
 'admin.web.co.id\n',
 'agree.web.co.id\n',
 'blue.web.co.id\n',
 'business.web.co.id\n',
 'cdn.web.co.id\n',
 'choose.web.co.id\n',
 'claim.web.co.id\n',
 'cl.web.co.id\n',
 'click.web.co.id\n',
 'confirm.web.co.id\n',
 'confirmation.web.co.id\n',
 'connect.web.co.id\n',
 'download.web.co.id\n',
 'enroll.web.co.id\n',
 'find.web.co.id\n',
 'group.web.co.id\n',
 'http.web.co.id\n',
 'https.web.co.id\n',
 'https-www.web.co.id\n',
 'install.web.co.id\n']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From another question: [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines) .

A good approach is instead of using `.readlines()`, which as you've noticed includes `\n` characters, and instead using something like.

```
with open('dictionaries/examples.txt') as f:
    websamples = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

This uses a couple of 'fancier' Python features, that help make it more pythonic.

- A context manager with the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement, which automatically closes the file handle at the end of the block, without having to manually call `.close()`.
- A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) used to create a new array by calling  `.rstrip()` on each line as it is read from the input file.

Comment: Nice! thank you very much for the help it works well. I want to upvote your comment but I don't have the ability to do that yet, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for accepting the answer, and welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @Tsukuru - I upvoted it for you :)